# My site uploaded on Git hub doesn't load with CSS on net but it loads correctly with chrome on my laptop

Tags: html, css, github

I uploaded my own created personal site on Github (includes CSS and HTML only). The link doesn't open the site very well as my CSS contents doesn't get displayed but when I open the same file locally on my chrome browser it opens correctly.
Below I'm attaching the 2 screenshots of what it's like when I open.

1)With Github(Error while loading)

2)Locally opened using VScode(Correctly opened)

I was hoping that my uploaded file gets opened correctly like did in VScode so that I can share the link of my site.I am mentioning the link here too if anyone finds the fault then please help me rectify it.
https://dewansh28.github.io/PersonalSite/

Comment: paths on most servers are case sensitive, but not on your windows computer. So your folder is named `CSS` but you try to import from `css`.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It worked correctly when I changed the path from css to CSS
Thankyou!